# Using python cryptography to differentiate TLS1.3 rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 from TLS1.3 rsa_pss_pss_sha256 certificates

Tags: python, openssl, tls1.3, python-cryptography

I generated two certificates using openssl cli. The first (if I'm not wrong) should be rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 and the second (dito) should be rsa_pss_pss_sha256.

```
openssl genpkey -out ca-rsa.key.pem -algorithm RSA
openssl genpkey -out ca-rsa-pss.key.pem -algorithm RSA-PSS

# rsae
openssl req -x509 -days 1 -subj "/CN=ca-rsae" \
            -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sha1 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:20 \
            -key ca-rsa.key.pem -out ca-rsae.cert.pem
            

# rsa-pss
openssl req -x509 -days 1 -subj "/CN=ca-rsa-pss" \
            -key ca-rsa-pss.key.pem -out ca-rsa-pss.cert.pem
```

Using openssl to print the two certificate gives the following (truncated for briefly) result:

```
# rsae
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ca-rsae.cert.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption

# rsa-pss
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ca-rsa-pss.cert.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsassaPss
```

Now I'm trying to determine the TLS SignatureScheme of each certificate using cryptography but it seems that the lib doesn't distinguish `Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption` from `Public Key Algorithm: rsassaPss` and just create an RSAPublicKey object for both:

```
>>> for cert in (rsae, rsa_pss):
...     print(cert.public_key())
...     print(cert.signature_algorithm_oid)
...     print(cert.signature_algorithm_parameters)
...     print(cert.signature_hash_algorithm)
...     print()
...

<cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl.rsa.RSAPublicKey object at 0x7f35b8dbd850>
<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.2.840.113549.1.1.10, name=RSASSA-PSS)>
<cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding.PSS object at 0x7f35b9c4ec50>
<cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA1 object at 0x7f35b9c4ec50>

<cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl.rsa.RSAPublicKey object at 0x7f35b8dbd850>
<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.2.840.113549.1.1.10, name=RSASSA-PSS)>
<cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding.PSS object at 0x7f35b9c4f010>
<cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA256 object at 0x7f35b9c4f010>
```

I expected the public key to have an attribute to differentiate the two, kind of signature_algorithm_oid but for the public key. Introspecting the object (dir), no such attribute seems to exist.

Hence the question, how to differentiate the two using the cryptography python library?